# Generate RESTful Web Service Client in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, rest, wsdl

I have developed a restful java web service using jersey in eclipse. Now I need to generate the client side for this web service. I know this is possible in Netbeans, but how can it be done in eclipse?

So far I have tried creating a new *web service client* in *New->Other->Web Services* but it asks for a service definition in the form of a WSDL, WSIL or HTML document. How can I generate these? As far as I know, there is no WSDL for REST because services are openly described.

Also If it is possible to generate a client, can it be done inside the REST web service project itself?

Comment: The vogella url is not a client, it just creates a webservice.
I recommend the following url instead.
https://crunchify.com/how-to-create-restful-java-client-with-jersey-client-example/

Answer (score 2):

To generate a client project you can use Eclipse wizard "New Maven Project":
See example http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMaven/article.html

To create a call to REST service from client you can use Jersey Client API:
See example https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html